# Проблема с overflow:hidden

Tags: css

Для основного родительского блока задано свойство `overflow:hidden`. 
Нужно подвинуть плашку за родительский блок вправо, но `overflow:hidden` мешает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить это?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```css
.relative-wrap {    
    position: relative;
}
.overflow-wrap {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;        
}

.div {
    position: absolute;  top: 50px; left: 225px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;    
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-wrap">    
    <div class="overflow-wrap">        
        <div class="div"></div>        
    </div>   
</div>
```